# Отозванный сертификат при установке MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не устанавливается Sql server management studio.Пишет про сбой в установке. Лог ошибки: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/xoEUKs1NZipe4w.В версии 17.9.1 идет выполнение пакетов, все нормально качает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скачать инсталлятор поновее?

Comment: Ну и за что минусуете?

Comment: @Qwertiy судя по версии - этот самый новый

Comment: Читайте лог, ищите что именно не смогло скачать

Comment: Кинул ссылку на лог. Windows обновлен до последней версии, несколько раз перезагрузил ноут . Пишет о неизвестной ошибке.

Comment: а может кто то по дороге подменил сертификат? ну какой то ркн.

Comment: @KoVadim не понял тебя

Comment: @KoVadim . Суть в том что на компе установилось на ноуте нет. Те же действия проделал

Comment: другой днс. или может там сертификат на самом деле лицензия. И разрешает установку только один раз или на определенный вид железа (например, только на интел)

Comment: в интернетах пишут, что это ssmc и антивирус.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130225/discussion-between-alexander-and-kovadim).

Answer (score 0):

Наконец-то я нашел решение. Надо было скачать последнюю версию vc-redist, ссылка ниже
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170